# Merge a branch of a repository to another repository sharing a part of history

Tags: git, git-merge

I think I've made mistakes in a migration from svn to git and now I'm in the following situation:

I have old import from which I've created a branch

```
O1--O2--O3
          \-B1--B2
```

And a new import with new commits

```
N1--N2--N3--N4--N5
```

Where N1=01, N2=O2...
Is it possible to build a repository with this history ?

```
N1--N2--N3--N4--N5
         \-B1--B2
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a branch `b` pointing to commit `B2` and a branch `n` pointing to commit `N5` in the same repository. (If they're in different repositories, you may `git fetch` branches, even if they are unrelated, to get them into the same one.)

Then

```
git checkout b
git rebase N3
```

Where `N3` is (as in your ASCII art illustrations) the commit on the `n` branch that would be the most recent common ancestor of `n` and `b`, had the history not be duplicated.

Git will automatically recognize and eliminate the (content-wise) duplicated commits and only rewrite the ones unique to branch `b`, thus leading to your desired result

Comment: For the moment I have two repositories, and I must make something wrong because if I fetch the branch from old repository to the new repository and apply your solution I have a lot of conflicts, even on files not modified in any branch after the junction point.